# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I got this project from a repo cloned it using

git clone

then cd into the correct directory

Example:
[image: Example]

Next i went to install the project and this error comes up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1NdC.png)

Here is the JSON file

```
{
  "name": "tryb-prints",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "atomize": "^1.0.26",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "firebase": "^8.0.2",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.1",
    "shopify-buy": "^2.11.0",
    "styletron-engine-atomic": "^1.4.6",
    "styletron-react": "^5.2.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

any help at all would be apricated

Answer (score 41):

try with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: This worked in my case, where we all were using npm 6.x and someone tried their luck with 7.x.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed almost 2 days of debugging

Answer (score 4):

Using `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` allows you to get passed those errors.

Answer (score 2):

Because some of your inner dependency is forcing react ^16.8 you cant use version 17+.

Downgrade to anything below major version 17 and you are good to go

Comment: Do i just need to downgrade react version or change in json file

Comment: Hey Cathal. It depends. I would just go for changing it in package json (remove the ^ for a second), install and put the ^ back.  That should be the safest and quick

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I was facing a similar issue with npm and I'm glad I saw your post. This definitely worked for me!